# How did our Meta writing challenge test run go?

Tags: discussion, writing-exercise

We finished our [test run](//writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/writing-challenge-test-run-april-20-2017-may-11) for the [Meta writing challenges](//writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/) recently - but how did it go?

Was there anything that happened that wasn't expected? Were there any problems? Is there anything that could be improved for the next one? What should we keep in mind when starting the next challenge?

Answer (score 6):

The challenge was left open-ended, with just a faint suggestion of a prompt, so we got quite a variety.  I don't know if that's good or bad; I found it a little hard to get started because it felt *so* open-ended, but in the end I decided to go with that thematic hint even though nobody else did, and that allowed me to write something.  So I'd suggest, from my own experience and because it seemed to work ok in the chat challenges, to have *some* sort of prompt.  It should be something that lends itself to a variety of approaches -- a short phrase or a theme has seemed to work well in the past.

Answer (score 3):

I would be happy to give it another go, and with a more concrete prompt :)

Answer (score 2):

I was very late in finally deciding on a topic to write.. but it was very good.
Have more soon.