# Writing challenge - 9 Aug 2017 - 29 Aug 2017 - Television

Tags: discussion, writing-exercise

Welcome back to the Writing Challenge!

After [feedback received](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1297/13002), it was decided that the next one should include a prompt. So, here are two options:

- **Challenge**

Write something about *television*. This is based off what my daughter is doing while she's sick with a fever.

- **Prompt**

  > [...] blinked. "My eyes are dry," [s/he|name] said around a yawn.

Both of these options are *optional* - feel free to write something completely unrelated as well.

---

So to enter the challenge, you simply write something, and post it below. It can be a work in progress, and continue working on it while receiving feedback, or it can be a finished work - anything goes.

You can submit your entries until the end of the three weeks. After three weeks, we'll choose the next prompt and put up a new post.

You can either post the whole thing here, or, if you usually post your writing somewhere else, you can put a link here - although I'd advise putting something in to get people interested.

Remember: **this is *not* a contest.** This is merely for fun, and for some practice writing. There will (hopefully) be writers of all different skill levels posting - *I'm* certainly not super good.

You're welcome to provide feedback, but please make sure that it's constructive. And remember: **[Be Nice](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)**.

Remember that the age limit for the site is 13 - so please avoid excessive graphic content or strong language.

---

I look forward to reading the submissions!

Helpful: [The original post](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1275/13002) that started all this. All these challenges can be seen under the [writing-exercise](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-exercise) tag.

Comment: Thanks to @Mithrandir, who's a bit busy to post this one but has asked me to help out. Thanks for getting this started! (Most of the text here is from their past posts.)

Comment: You spelled my name wrong, but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Mithrandir  - Fixed!

Comment: Are their any style requirements? Because from the title of this post I thought the objective would be a TV script :P

Comment: @WeckarE. No style requirements, just have fun.

Answer (score 6):

"But mommy, I don't *want* a television, all the neighbors have RES!" 
"A what now?"
"A RES, Reality Emulation System, you know that."
"But those things aren't good for you, those kids live in that reality all the time..."
"It helps with learning, I swear! You can play in physics worlds!"
"Right, yes, I know. It's nonsense. I'm at least getting you a television."
"Why, what else would you get me? It's the least you could do."
"Honey, have you ever heard of a computer in your classes?"
"A what now?"
"Or a book? A record player? A cassette tape? VHS?"
"Come on, stop being crazy. The RES section is over here."
"Honey..."
"For my birthday! Please?"
"Your birthday is two months away."
"Well, at least I'm not asking for the full simulator system. That allows you to be 100% in the world - smell, taste, touch. Everything!"
"You are *not* getting that."
"Mom, come on, here's the basic RES package. Just sight. It's cheap, too!"
*::sighs::* "Well, come on, then."

After a harrowing conversation with the salesman, a monetary loss, a quick step home in the Trans, and a couple hours devoted to the setup of the device, she was tired, and sank into a chair, only to hear the question that every parent inwardly groans at:

"Hey mom, what's this?"
"What's what, honey?"
"Here, put these on."
"Fine, fine. Whoa..."
"What is it?"
"I can't believe it...we actually have some of these you know. Would you like a real one?"
"Yeah, these things are cool! You move your hand and sort of lift over this thin sheet, and then it talks to you about what's marked on each sheet."
After a shuffle over to a nearby shelf, and a breath to blow off dust -
"Here's one."
"Can you tell me what it says?"
"Yeah, I can even teach you how to figure out what it says."
"Oh, that would be great - my classes are so boring."
"This used to be taught in classes, you know. How about I make us some hot cocoa? I can translate it too you."
They sat in their chairs, sipping their drink. "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times..."

A month later...

There in the living unit, there stood a shelf. On that shelf stood several things: a dusty RES, and five books, each well worn. Near the shelf was a cradle, and a young girl was...what was it called? *reading* to the baby within. The mother sat in a chair nearby, tired but happy. She looked from the RES to the books to the children, and smiled. This was a nice living unit. No, no, not living unit. This was a nice *home*.

---

Apologies for the pretty junk writing, I've always been terrible at it. Suggestions are welcome =)

Answer (score 4):

**This is very much a work in progress; I am quite literally still writing it, even though it was posted. But I'd appreciate critique while I'm in the middle, so y'all get to watch the process ;)**

---

I wrinkled my nose in disgust at the ugly, squat, creature sitting it front of me at the table. It was a goblin - a disgusting fat green creature with horrible huge eyes and  absolutely nauseating breath. Perhaps worst of all, this one had a trail of slime all across its face from the slug sandwich it was eating. Yes, a *slug* sandwich, as horrible as it sounds.

Those huge eyes slowly blinked. "My eyes are dry," Darlok said around a yawn.
"Of course, Mr. Darlok," I said, my green eyes watering from the stench of his breath. Ugh! It was worse than rotting dragon eggs. "Would you like a moisture pad for your eyes?"

He waved his wrinkled green hand. "No, no," he said in his deep, croaking voice - it always reminded me of a bullfrog. "Your poor-quality pads will only make it worse."

I tried not to clench my teeth in anger.

"We are the most reputable restaurant in Lopwood, Mr. Darlok," I said - rather testily, I'm afraid. "Our moisture pads for goblin eyes are the highest quality pads available in —"

The goblin put up his hand. "Nay, nay," he said, laughing with his bullfrog-like voice. "I will manage."

"Of course, sir," I said, opening and closing my hand behind my back. "Would you like anything else, sir?"

The goblin shook his ugly head. "I will remain here for a while. I will ring the bell if I require anything, waiter."
He smirked. "Now shoo!"

"Of course, sir," I said, and walked back through the restaurant to the kitchen.

Once I reached the bustling kitchen, I sat down on a chair and ran my fingers through my short brown hair. Ugh! That goblin was the bane of my existence. Ever since I arrived at this restaurant 5 years ago, a scrawny and starving elven child, he had been driving me crazy. He was a regular at the Lopwood Cafe, and he always ordered one of the disgusting goblin foods that we only reluctantly carried. Sometimes it was a slug sandwich, sometimes a frog casserole, occasionally a newt stew. I *hated* those. They made my pointed ears quiver. Even just *thinking* about it almost made me gag.

I sat there for a minute, grinding my teeth, until someone plopped down next to me. "What's up?" asked Talleta.

Talleta was short. Probably because she's a pixie - I hadn't really met anyone from that species who could be described as *tall* exactly. In fact, she looks sort of like a child from my species. A green haired and green eyed, green tinted skinned child with pointed ears.

I sighed. “Nothing,” I replied. “Just Darlok being annoying again.”

She wrinkled her green nose. “Oh, him,” she said, sighing. “Just ignore him. He’s a bit of a jerk, but he’s a pretty good customer.”

"I know," I said. "And that's what makes him annoying."

She laughed. "Come on, let's go see if Cook could use any help."

She hopped off the chair and wandered off towards the cook, a fat old human woman. I stayed sitting a moment longer, then got up to join them.

---

When dinner rush was over, I was finally able to escape from the downstairs restaurant. I mean, I'm grateful that they took me in, but... there's a limit to how long I can stay serving food to demon families with screaming kids that are always spontaneously combusting.

I ran up the rickety wooden stairs in the back of the building. There I could find the room that I slept in, with all of my possessions. I say 'all', but there really weren't that many. I had a couple books that I had rescued when an unlucky young wizard left them behind, mostly about lands in the far north and the creatures that lived there. I had a carved wooden box in which I kept my earnings. Along with the money, I kept a green necklace - a gift for Talleta, when her birthday arrived. And finally, I had a small, blue gem - my only keepsake from my parents.

I flopped into the hard wooden bed with a thin mattress that the restaurant had provided me with, and drifted off to sleep.

Comment: Hope you're gonna to give it an end. You may be out of time for the challenge (and you kinda repeated "disgusting" a bunch of times at the start) but I'm damn curious of what happens next.

Comment: @Liquid - sure, I'll try to at least finish the sentence ;P. And good point about the repetitive 'disgusting' in the beginning; thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: Took me longer than I had planned, but I finished the sentence and adjusted the wording in the beginning...

Answer (score 3):

***This is my first ever attempt at entering in a piece to a writing challenge/submitting my writing to the public so I do appreciate any constructive feedback and this is still a work in progress.  If this is too long let me know too and I can cut it down I wasn't sure if there was any length requirements.***

---

Dawn was breaking over the peaks of the Feruk Mountains. Through the faint light of morning, the image of a lone orc was standing on the edge of the Gorak Cliff.  He was pacing on the edge overlooking the forest below, anger swelling in his chest as he leered into the forest. Enough light though, to trace the muscular outline of his monstrous, black body as he peered out. Quiet, except for the sound of his harsh breath flowing through his large nostrils. The longer he stared into the forest, the more his body seethed with hate.  His broad shoulders heaved with every breath as he clenched two large battle axes, one in each hand.

"TERU'KA MA KARU'TE VUDAMEHA!"

His sudden roar bellows out from the mountains into the forest below with an out pour of malice and anger. Out from the rocks behind him, five wargs appeared from the shadows and prowled to the edge with a low growl. The rest of the world was about to find out that Kharr Drakil made his declaration of war.

With a heavy sigh, Kharr strapped the axes to his back.

"Erule!" Kharr called out to his alpha warg.

Erule stepped forward from the other wargs. With a quick flick of his body, Kharr mounted Erule and turned his head to look into the forest one more time.  He shakes his head back and forth in dismay before letting out a final huff.

"Let's go!" Kharr grunts to his wargs as he rode off to meet with his escort and head home.

As Kharr passed through the Gorukai Horde territory, frustrations crept back into thought.  Village after village destroyed, pillaged, and burned. Whole clans erased from existence.  Families destroyed and huts left in ruin as smoke rose from the ashes. All for the sport of man. The Gorukai weren't the most developed of the orcs or had the best wealth, but they made do; too proud to ever ask for help. Their territory was not large, only taking a small corner of the west side.  The Feruk Mountains shielded them to the north and west except for a small mountain pass.  It was there the orcs were most vulnerable.  On the other side of the pass lays Herum River.  A river which separates the mountains from the forest and provides a boarder between orc and man.

"HALT!" Kharr commands as he raises a closed first.

Dismounting, Kharr darts his eyes around the area to ensure it was safe. As he scans the area with his eyes, he began to make his way towards a pile of ash that was once a home.  He crouches down and clenches some ash into his hand before opening it and letting the ash drift into the wind.

'Ambushed... during the night...The ash still warm from the fires.  Only way those pink skins can enter is through the gate at Bardur Pass... Tarka, why didn't you send a messenger...you should have known I was coming to change guard.  We have guarded that pass together for centuries from man...'
Mid thought, Kharr notices an object in the ash.

'No!'

Kharr's heart dropped as he picks it up and realizes what it was.

'Man will pay for this. Our lands are not hunting grounds for the sport of man to torture, kill and enslave! We will rise from the ashes of despair.  We will rise from the fires of anger.  We will rise up as one race, one horde, one nation.  We will no longer be slaves of man!'

Kharr slams his fist into his chest.  He knows what he needs to do now. After years of training the Drakil Horde into a war machine, Kharr's vision of the future is coming to pass.

Kharr rushes back to Erule and as he mounts one of the escorts ask "What did you see in the ashes my Lord?"

"You will find out soon enough."

Kharr sits and ponders for a moment.
"Hmmm... yes...." Kharr mumbles to himself. "We Ride to the Capital of Gorukai Horde... Gorkar!"

"Harad!" Kharr points to one of his escorts. A young Orc who has not yet seen his first real battle and fresh out of training.

"Go to Drakar.  Tell them to send out the 3rd Legion and meet us in Gorkar by nightfall tomorrow!" Kharr positions himself to face Harad.

"This will be your first test. Mess it up and you can consider yourself a bloody cook for the rest of your life!"

"Ye-ye-yes my Lord! By my honor I will not fail."

With that Harad rode off in a dash towards Drakar, the capital of the Drakil Horde.  As Harad fades into the distance, Thrak, General of the 1st Legion, starts chuckling.

"Kharr, why did you go and scare the poor kid? He hasn't even seen battle yet or spent a night with a female!"

He was the only orc who was able to not use honorifics, and keep his head. Thrak seemed amused at the hazing. Being a soldier was the greatest honor to the Drakil who above all else, coveted the glory of battle. Being stripped of your ranking was humiliating,  removal was of the highest dishonor.  Kharr scoffs at Thrak.

"This is nothing compared to what we had to go through." Wincing at the memories of his youth.

Thrak bursts out into a hearty laugh. He thought back to their training days together when he and Kharr were still young.  Kharr often would get a lashing for his lack of discipline.

"Yeah! And They told you that you would amount to nothing! HA... look at us now!"

A rare smile cracks across Kharr's face thinking about all the trouble they use to get into.  His father, the previous Warlord of the Drakil, was always lecturing him. The constant reminders about his responsibilities and inheritance to the horde. Now, distant memories of the past.  His smile faded to sadness as his thoughts dive deeper into memories better kept locked up.  Thrak notices the change of mood and rides up to him placing a hand on his shoulder.

"Let's go brother. We can't change the past, but we can change the future.  The Gorukai need us."

Kharr returns to reality with his eyes fixed on the road ahead.  Reminded of the mission at hand as he feels the object still in his grasp.  He nods to Thrak as he collects himself before issuing a command.

"To Gorkar!"

Kharr races down the path to Gorkar, his escort falling in line behind.  He could not afford to waste anymore time with idle chats or distant memories.